# Can i use flutter isolate for backround processes without touching Java/Kotlin?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I'm trying to create an app that manages a BLE connection in the background (receives notifications, reconnects and subscribes to a characteristic when connection is lost and the phone is moved near the BLE device again).

Right now I have the app somewhat built - everything that I need works relatively well but only when the app is open. Although the code isn't up to standard as this is my first app and I don't have any previous experience with Java/Kotlin/Dart (this is also why I'd rather not touch anything outside of flutter).

I need the app to send me local push notifications when tabbed out of the app or when screen lock is on and as far as I understand one could do this with isolates. I've searched a lot but found one [guide](https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124#155c) which is kind of hard to understand as a beginner and also uses Kotlin.

Can I get away with only dart code for background code execution (described above) and is it suitable for a beginner?

Also, let me know if you have any alternative solutions since all I need is to get a notification on my phone whenever it receives a notification from a BLE device (and also auto connecting). I've already tried this with kivy since I'm more familiar with python but with no luck.

Comment: A package like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch) is probably the best you're gonna get.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about BLE there's this plugin by the way: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble

As for the isolates, they are not ideal for this even though they do run separately, they'll get killed eventually. There's also a little helper package that makes working with isolates very straightforward if you want to try it: https://pub.dev/packages/computer

And so actually for the task at hand (background execution) I would suggest researching/using this one: https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch

Comment: Does the flutter reactive ble package have any advantages over flutter blue packgae in terms of backround tasks? I'm currently using flutter blue. 
About using backround fetch - i think the problem with that is that it cant be reactive - I don't know when the notification will come through BLE before it actually comes.

Comment: Oh, flutter_blue is also nice, sure. So.. I didn't do this myself, but I think I'd try using isolates (put there the scanning) and then keep the app alive in background through background_fetch.. smth like this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not encourage you to use any timer-based solution that tries to wake up your phone every 15 minutes or so, since that uses unnecessary CPU time.

Now I'm not that much into Flutter, but at least on Android, the "correct" way to have an ongoing connection (auto-connect) is to have a Foreground Service in the process running, so the process does not get killed. Then subscribe to characteristic notifications as usual, and handle the values as they arrive, either in Java or Flutter (by using some Java <-> Dart bridge).